# Batch file to edit .ini file but do not delete blank space

Tags: batch-file

I am new to StackOverflow. I want to run a batch file to find and replace a single string in an .ini file. I tried several solutions given on stackoverflow and other sites too.

A few of them are working - but delete my other lines having "space" or ";".

Here is the string that I want to find and change in my file `RDConfigSettings.ini`

```
CommunicationMode:1
```

I want it vice-versa:

- if it is "CommunicationMode:1" then change it to "CommunicationMode:0"
- if it is "CommunicationMode:0" then change it to "CommunicationMode:1"

Here is the whole content of my `RDConfigSettings.ini` file

```
;0 for Staging, 1 for Pre-Production, 2 for Production
RDEnviroment:2
;0 for disable, 1 for Enable
RDServiceLogs:0
;0 for disable, 1 for Enable
ClientValidation:0
;Validate Management Server Certificate -- 0 for Yes, 1 for No
ValidateCertificate:0
;Proxy Configuration -- 0 for Direct Internet Access, 1 for Access via Proxy
ProxyConfig:0
ProxyIP:[Proxy IP]
ProxyPort:[Proxy Port]
;0 for Https, 1 for Http
CommunicationMode:1
;Port Range Setting in below field
PortBegin:11100
PortEnd:11120
;ManagementServerURL
Registration:https://rdm.smartbioplus.com/rdm-device-app/registration
Keyrotation:https://rdm.smartbioplus.com/rdm-key-management-app/keyRotation
Telemetry:https://rdm.smartbioplus.com/rdm-telemetry-app/telemetry
Domain:rdm.smartbioplus.com
URL_Port:443
```

Could anyone help me? THis is my code:

```
@echo off
set "file=E:\CSC Softwares\MorphoRdServiceL0Soft\RDConfigSettings.ini"
:loop
findstr "^CommunicationMode:0$" "%file%" >nul || (
  type "%file%"|repl "^CommunicationMode:1" "CommunicationMode:0" >"%file%.tmp"
  move "%file%.tmp" "%file%" >nul
)
timeout 120 >nul
goto :loop
```

Moreover, it will be a great help if someone can add an Command with administrative rights that will stop a particular service "MORPHO_RD_Service" before replacing the string and then after replace the string, start the same service again.

Comment: Show what code you are currently running that has that problem.

Comment: I tried `jrepl` too. But not much aware about commands. Hence unable to use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the need for an external utility such as jrepl, which is great for some things, but not needed for such a task:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "file=E:\CSC Softwares\MorphoRdServiceL0Soft\RDConfigSettings.ini"
for /f "tokens=1,*delims=]" %%i in ('type "%file%" ^| find /v /n "" ^& break^>"%file%"') do (
    set "line=%%j"
    if "!line!" == "CommunicationMode:1" (
       set "line=!line:1=0!"
       set "hold=!line!"
    ) else if "!line!" == "CommunicationMode:0" (
       set "line=!line:0=1!"
       set "hold=!line!"
  ) 
    echo(!line!>>"!file!"
 )
 echo Changed to !hold!
 pause
```

Comment: Thanks a bit. Your solution worked but, it created duplicate of all contents. Means all .ini contents are copied next to end of file and string replaced there only.

Comment: No. Still replicating the contents. also Command Window doesn't close itself. Plz test at your end.

Comment: Do me a favor, paste the entire code you copied from me, AS IS and post into your question. as a section below the current code. So I can see please.

Comment: Ah.. Thanks, @Stephan, I did not notice that.

Comment: @Stephan  @Gerhard
Yes. It's working changing the `break^>"%file%"` works. Great. Now let me to implement it with elevated command and test on my original file location with System Services stop and start.  
I will inform here shortly.

Comment: Thanks all of you. My batch file working perfectly now with Admin Rights (elevated command) alongwith stopping a particular service then replace the string and then again start that service again. Thanks a lot all of you

Comment: Cool. Can we clean up some comment please? here and on @Stephan's answer.

Comment: Great ...  
Thanks a lot. Everything working fine ... I am thanksfull to you with deep heart.

Comment: You do not yet have enough reputation yet to upvote and thank Stephan for his help, so I will upvote his answer for you.

Comment: I need further some help on this scrip. 
Could you help me

Answer (score 1):

You have code to switch from `1` to `0`, but no code to switch from `0` to `1`.
Below code alternates between `1` and `0` with each run of the loop.
I also changed to `jrepl` (more modern and powerful). It isn't necessary (though possible) to process piped data and redirect the result to another file. The `/f` switch gives the inputfile to process, the `/o` switch gives the outputfile. By giving it a single `-`, it uses the same filename as the input file (and overwrites it with the new(changed) data).

```
@echo off
set "file=t.txt"
:loop 
findstr "^CommunicationMode:" "%file%" & REM this line for troubleshooting only
findstr "^CommunicationMode:0$" "%file%"  >nul && ( 
  call jrepl "CommunicationMode:0" "CommunicationMode:1"  /f "%file%" /o -
) || (
  call jrepl "CommunicationMode:1" "CommunicationMode:0"  /f "%file%" /o -
) 
timeout 1 >nul 
goto :loop
```

Don't forget to adapt the data file name and the timeout to your needs.

Comment: Thanks @Stephan. It worked, but with help of `jrepl`.   
1st - could you make it without `jrepl`   
2nd it's auto changing the string after given seconds, could it be stopped on 1st change and if we need to change it again we can run the batch file again. Means change once in one run and stop.

Comment: 1st: To not use `jrepl`, just replace it with your `repl` command. If you don't want that too, @Gerhard already showed a pure batch solution (there is no point in copy/pasting it into my answer) 2nd: To not run in a loop, ... just remove `goto :loop`.